# How to put a strikethrough in a listview or repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I don't know to put in strikethrough in a listview or repeater.. I want to have a strikethrough  in description only..

here my asp code:

```
  <div class="price" CssClass="Sline"><%#RenderPrice2((decimal)Eval("lb_sellingprice"))%></div>
```

thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add to the css - you're already have the class for it

Comment: is there other choice rather than using css?

Comment: Well, there is... It's just it's so 1998 :P ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your description just add a CSS class and give it this rule:

```
.yourCSSClass {text-decoration: line-through;}

<asp:Label ID="lb_titleLabel" runat="server" CssClass="center-head" Text='<%# Eval("lb_title") %>' />
                 <p><asp:Label CssClass="yourCSSClass" ID="lb_descriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lb_description") %>' /></p>
```

Comment: @SilverFang CssClass is not a valid attribute for the HTML element <div>.  If you want to add multiple CSS classes you can specify multiple classes in the class attribute.  i.e. class="price Sline"